How to write believable characters with deep motivations and strong voices?
I have two narrators for my story, both of them are polar opposites but they're best friends. The first one is a Victorian actress while the other one is a painter. I want to write a character that is believable with a personality that really ties in with their actions. The actress is really good at her job and also has really good people skills. She's great at reading people. But over time she begins to dabble with gambling and alcohol. How can I write this slow descent but still keep her a character the readers will love, or at least mourn? The artist is strange and is obsessed with art. But when she realizes that she had given everything up for nothing, she kinda withdraws from the world. How can I create a personality that differentiates the two while also making them do things that makes sense for them to do? How can I tap into their heads?

Unfortunately, English is not my main language, so the translator may make ridiculous mistakes, but I am interested in trying to help you.
As for me, there is a fairly easy solution to the problem with the artist. It is obvious that an artist is a creative person and, often, the paintings he paints reflect the changes taking place in his life. Therefore, it is easiest to add to the text a description of the painted works (if not), which will become darker and, as it were, more gray (detached) than the first described works.
The artist is strange and is obsessed with art. But when she realizes that she had given everything up for nothing, she kinda withdraws from the world.
I think that an art-obsessed person, even disappointed in his desire, will continue to draw, even for himself, and not for others, but he will continue. And it will be quite authentic to show her grief through paintings.
About the actress, not everything is so clear, because a person with the skill of pretending, who is so good that he even gets paid for it (probably), will be able to hide his problems from others.
Here you need to look at the character's character, habits and some distinctive features. Many people go through such a stage of life as the "fall" in different ways.
The actress is really good at her job and also has really good people skills. She's great at reading people.
Even if she reads people perfectly and is quite sociable, some things will still be noticeable in conversation or in everyday life.
I would suggest trying to make for yourself a few (or more) so-called steps, which she will gradually descend. Here, an excellent example would be "The Devil's Advocate", in which the main character also, albeit for other reasons, goes through a period similar to the state of your hero. There are clearly highlighted "hooks", after which changes occur with the hero. Sometimes the "hook" is a conversation or event that has had a pretty strong effect on the character.
This will be a good reference for you. After the dialogue with the heroine, you can highlight for the readers (through the eyes of other characters) some moments that will later form a single picture. Whether it's a bruise on her arm from some drunken brawl performed by the heroine, to a stain on her shirt that she couldn't wash off.
To keep the reader's love for the character, you need to show it in a good light more often (Not enough money? Go to work!). Not just write "She helps homeless animals", but write it in such a way that there is a contrast with her appearance and inner world.
"Even though she was unable to walk home, this little fluffy lump in the doorway made her stop. She looked at him, thinking that they were somehow similar. From the fifth time, she was able to pick him up from the ground, wrapping him in some kind of coat lying nearby, and carry him to her, without even imagining what she would do with him next."
This is very "dirty", but I think the idea is clear.
